# Understanding how TFTP Server works

Tags: 14.04, cisco, tftp

I have an Ubuntu machine which acts as a TFTP Server. I want to configure my Cisco IOS routers to take configuration from this TFTP server at boot time.

I have a few doubts- Where do I store the configuration file for my Cisco router in the TFTP Server? Currently, I have created two temp folders in `/var/lib/tftpboot`-

```
automation@automation:/var/lib/tftpboot$ ls -l
total 8
drwx------ 2 tftp tftp 4096 Mar 31 15:37 ExrZHRa-incoming
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 31 15:52 TXJla-outgoing

automation@automation:/var/lib/tftpboot$ tree
.
├── ExrZHRa-incoming [error opening dir]
└── TXJla-outgoing
    └── R1.txt

2 directories, 1 file
```

As per Cisco's documentation, this is the syntax to get a file from TFTP server-

```
copy tftp: [[[//location ]/directory ]/filename ] nvram:startup-config 

Example:
Device# copy tftp://server1/dir10/datasource nvram:startup-config
```

As per my understanding, the `location` will be IP of my TFTP Server and `filename` will be the actual config file to be loaded. But what should be configured in the `directory`? I tried `/var/lib/tftpboot/TXJla-outgoing` but it didn't work.

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use something [like this configuration guide](https://medium.com/@Sciri/configuring-a-tftp-server-on-ubuntu-for-switch-upgrades-and-maintenance-caf5b6833148), the *root* of the TFTP server is `/var/lib/tftpboot/`.

If this is the root, and the file is directly in there then your tftp command will look like this:

```
copy tftp://ip.add.re.ss/FILENAME nvram:startup-config
```

LIke a web server, the 'root' of the TFTP server's config is the root directory on-disk that your server will serve from; this is *omitted* in the remote system that's doing the copying.